# Проблема с модальным окном Bootstrap5

Tags: bootstrap

И так, вот код моего модального она на Bootstrap-5

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <div id="logform" class="radial">
                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="login_name">{login-method}</label><input type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name" /></li>
                        <li><label for="login_password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" /></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="login_not_save" id="login_not_save" value="1"/><label for="login_not_save">&nbsp;another's computer</label></li>
                        <li><button onclick="submit();" type="submit" title="Login">Login</button></li>
                    </ul>
                    <input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

но, когда я вызываю модал. окно по нажатию на кнопку

```
<button class="buttons" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">[group=5]Login[/group][not-group=5]Menu[/not-group]</button>
```

то окно открывается, и через долю секунды оно закрывается, но если в конец url вставить `#` то оно откроется, как сделать так, чтобы она открывалась только по нажатию на кнопку, без `#` в конце url. вот [видео](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSKB0.jpg)

Дополнительный вопрос (не основной)
можно ли установить цвет модельному окну? просто у меня сайт в чёрных тонах, а окно белое

Comment: отдельные вопросы и задавать следует отдельно.

Comment: не вижу на видео чтоб что-то открывалось и через долю секунды закрывалось. у вас при нажатии на кнопку просто страница перезагружается.

Comment: а как сделать чтобы не закрывалась?

Comment: `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/background/` классы для фона припишите да и все

Comment: хорошо, но как фиксануть проблему?

Comment: `button` замените на `a`, или вне формы его сделайте